# Saving unique data in a loop for multiple many-to-one relationships in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one

I am currently working with tables with multiple many-to-one relationships and I'm trying to implement all of them using Hibernate.

For example, three tables I have are:

Product(id, pname), Users(id, pid, gid, uname), Group(id, gname)

Group is in an one-to-many relationship with Users

Product is also in an one-to-many relationship with Users

Users is in a many-to-one relationship with both Product and Group.

A sample of data I would receive is below:

```
Line 0: pname   uname   gname
Line 1: Razer   Billy   admin
Line 2: Razer   Sally   admin
Line 3: Razer   Benji   admin
Line 4: Yahoo   Molly   admin
...
```

From the above example, I want my Product table to end up with only two entries (Razer and Yahoo) with Razer associated with three entries on the Users table and Yahoo associated with one entry on the Users table.

I also want my Group table to end up with only one entry ("admin") that is associated with four entries on the Users table.

So far, whenever I receive a new line of data, how do I make sure that *no duplicate entries* are created for the Product and Group table but rather referencing to *existing ones* on there?

For example, if Line 5's data is: **Razer   Jacky   admin**, how do I make sure that the Users table adds a new entry "Jacky" while this entry is associated with the entry "Razer" and "admin" already created rather than creating duplicate entries in the Product and Group table?

My correct flawed loop for the data goes like this:

```
// Three lists of same size created, 
// each list is a column of the sample data from above
// ...

Set<Users> users = new HashSet<Users>();
for(int i = 0; i < plist.size; i++){
     Product ptemp = new Product(plist.get(i));
     Group gtemp = new Group(glist.get(i));
     Users utemp = new Users(ptemp, gtemp, ulist.get(i));

     users.add(utemp);

     ptemp.setUsers(users);
     gtemp.setUsers(users);

     session.save(ptemp);
     session.save(gtemp);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lets go with the example you provided. You want to insert a new row -  **Razer Jacky admin**

Its a two step process
First of all check if product **Razer** and group **admin** is present in your database. If yes load them, If not create new objects for them.

Next step is rather straightforward you only need to persist the user data by adding references you loaded or created in first step.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Just to clarify, by persist, do you mean adding hibernate annotations (cascade persist) to both Product and Group?  By the same logic, can I check for presence in database also using hibernate annotations?

Comment: Since you are not sure weather product or group is already present in your DB. You have to explicitly load them by finding them. It can't be done using `cascade`. If you use Cascade in this case you'll end up having duplicate entries in `product` and `group`